# Optimization, performance, or efficiency not due to algorithm or strategy

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, programming

Is there any idiomatic way to describe the aspect of optimization, performance, or efficiency that is not due to choice of algorithm or strategy? I'm not necessarily looking for formal computer science terminology but it shouldn't seem too odd in a casual programming context.

Comment: There's always Serendipity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be described as an [*empirical*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+empirical) approach.

An empirical action is one that has been seen to work, although there may be no determinable scientific or logical reason as to why it works.